# Why is "use" not allowed, as in "use strict;" in Perl 5.14?

Tags: perl, shebang, use-strict

I am trying to use the following conventions I have been instructed to use for good/proper/safe Perl code for my `"Hello, World!"` Program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

I have created and successfully run the following "Hello World" program using (Strawberry) Perl 5.12 on my main Windows 7 OS:

```
!#/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, World!\n";
```

What I got back, as expected, was `"Hello, World!"`.

What struck me as very odd was that the same program run in terminal on my virtualized Linux Mint 14 OS, using Perl 5.14, produced the following error:

```
"use" not allowed in expression at /PATH/hello_world.pl line 2, at end of line
syntax error at /PATH/hello_world.pl line 2, near "use strict"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at /PATH/hello_world.pl line 3.
```

I created other "Hello World" programs subsequently without either the `use strict;` or `use warnings;` lines, and also one with the `-w`, which I had seen in some tutorials, indicating, if I am not mistaken, that warnings would be turned on.

Both of my alternate versions worked properly in that they produced my expected result:

```
Hello, World!
```

What I cannot be sure of is if I need the `use` statements in Perl programs from version 5.14 and up or if it is just fine to write the `-w` at the end of my first line.

I would like to think that I could use a consistent header, so to speak, in all of my Perl programs, whether they are Windows or Linux, Perl 5.12 or 5.14 or otherwise.

Comment: Did you ftp this to your Linux box?  Did you use text mode?

Comment: "use" is very definitely allowed :)  The problem is something else - perhaps, as Edward Thomson is suggesting, your source file got corrupted when you ftp'ed it from one PC to another.

Comment: Did not FTP. Using VirtualBox with Linux Mint 14. Not using text mode.

Comment: I created a screenshot to show my attempts with different versions of my "Hello, World!" program here: [link](http://bayimg.com/haiBMAAej).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your image shows that all of your scripts start with `!#/usr/bin/perl`. This is wrong. It is not a valid she-bang line, it is read as negation `!` followed by a comment `#`. The parsing will continue and with **script1.pl** perl will execute `! print "Hello world.\n";`. This will print `Hello world` and negate the result of `print` ... not really useful, but valid perl.

In **script2.pl** perl sees `! use strict;` and this is a compile time error and therefor perl fails and reports the error for the line `use strict;`.

So if you use correct she-bang lines, all three scripts will work as designed.

*Edit (test scripts added):*

**script1.pl**

```
!#/usr/bin/perl

print "Hello world.\n" ;
```

Calling `perl script1.pl` gives

```
Hello world.
```

**script2.pl**

```
!#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings ;

print "Hello world.\n" ;
```

Calling `perl script2.pl` gives

```
"use" not allowed in expression at script2.pl line 3, at end of line
syntax error at script2.pl line 3, near "use strict "
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at script2.pl line 4.
```

Using the correct syntax **script3.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

print "Hello world.\n" ;
```

Calling `perl script3.pl` gives

```
Hello world.
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the cause of the problem here. I could verify it.

Comment: Your *script1.pl* doesn't ignore the wrong shebang line, because obviously when you write `!#` it isn't a shebang line. It's the `!` (not) operator, followed by a comment. So it's the same as writing `!print`: inverting the return value of the `print` statement — which of course is ignored anyway. Where as in *script2.pl* it's doing `!use`, which doesn't make sense because `use` is a compile-time construct, not a run-time function.

Comment: @Smylers You are right, I changed my answer to give the correct reason for the failure. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I feel so much better knowing that I just made a simple mistake!

Answer (score 9):

You did something like

```
use warnings
use strict;
```

instead of

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

---

Actually, I think it might be a line ending issue. You have LF where you should have CR LF or vice-versa. I've seen this cause Perl to think the code starts halfway through the shebang line (e.g. `perl use strict;`)

---

As mentioned elsewhere, the code you posted and the code you used is different. You actually used

```
!use strict;
```

due to a bad shebang line.

```
!#/u...         # Negation followed by a comment
```

should be

```
#!/u...         # Shebang
```

Comment: Is there any way I can test this by adding an extra line break at the end of the shebang line? Could I use "\n"?

Comment: I tested with `-w` at the end of the shebang line, and with `"\n"` as well, and neither changed the output/error. I found the following [document](https://community.plus.net/forum/index.php?topic=43650.0;prev_next=next) which discusses how to deal with CR/LF issues between Windows and Linux. Again, I tried warning mode, which it suggests you implement in order to prevent the issue you've just mentioned from happening, but nothing changed. I don't see why I would have a CR LF issue writing and running these basic programs on a fresh linux install, though. I didn't FTP them at all.